# Store on single result from query into a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I have this table:

```
id     Name              Age 
------ ----------------- ----
10015  Phill             12
10016  Anne              14
```

I need only the Phill´s age. So I do:

```
SELECT Age FROM Persons WHERE id = 10015
```

But I need to save that information into a variable.

If I do this:

```
DECLARE @age Int
SET @age = SELECT Age FROM Persons WHERE Name LIKE 'Phill'
```

I get this *error*:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

Comment: SELECT @age = Age FROM Persons WHERE Name LIKE 'Phill'.   Although you may also want to put SELECT TOP 1 in there since there could be two or more Phills.

Comment: Its just an example........... I´ll edit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SET @age = (SELECT Age FROM Persons WHERE id = 10015)
```

This is the syntax for `SET` using a `SELECT`

Comment: I would use the second option that Gordon used below. It is clear and has the distinct advantage that you can set more than 1 variable in a single pass.

Comment: Yes it does deal with the OPs issue. I was just suggesting a better approach to help the OP learn instead of just taking this and running with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ways to do this:

```
DECLARE @age Int;
SET @age = (SELECT Age FROM Persons WHERE Name LIKE 'Phill');

DECLARE @age Int;
SELECT @age = Age FROM Persons WHERE Name LIKE 'Phill';

DECLARE @age Int = (SELECT Age FROM Persons WHERE Name LIKE 'Phill');
```